# How to draw arc based on decimals using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, trigonometry

I have a circle that I've drawn starting at -pi/2 to 3(pi)/2 to make a full circle. On top of it I have an arc that goes around the circle based on the decimal value it receives. So a value of 0.5 should fill the circle halfway, 0.9 should go around the circle 90%, etc.

I know that my start angle for the arc would be the same as the first circle (which is -pi/2), however how would I calculate my end angle?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Edit the original question to ask it _better_ if you didn't ask it well the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do an example. Suppose your percentage factor is `0.5`. A full circle is `2*pi` radians. Now multiply your percentage factor: `0.5` of that is `2*pi*0.5` radians (which happens to be `pi`). But you want to start at `-pi/2`, so add that: `pi` plus `-pi/2` is `pi/2`. So you would start at `-pi/2` and end at `pi/2`.

Now let's do the `0.9` example. It's the same: you would start at `-pi/2` and end at `2*pi*0.9 - pi/2`.

As a sanity check, here's what I get when I actually *draw* the `0.9` example using those numbers (this is Swift code but I don't think that will prove to be any difficulty):

```
let b = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:100,y:100), radius: 50, 
                     startAngle: -.pi/2, endAngle: 2*(.pi)*0.9 - .pi/2, 
                     clockwise: true)
```

[image]

Here is a chart that you can use to do a further sanity check (but watch out because they have chosen to make the numbers grow counter-clockwise):

[image]

Keep in mind that you can always add or subtract 2*pi to convert the same value from negative to positive or vice versa if you need to. Thus -pi/2 and 3*pi/2 take you to the same place on the circle ultimately.

Comment: Ah so it would be 2*pi*decimal + pi/2 to account for the negative starting point?

Comment: `2*pi*decimal - pi/2` if you express the starting point as negative.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Added a screen shot of the actual formula in action! I think it shows that we get the kind of results you are after.